# Pass path from Assets in Android

Tags: java, android, chunk-templates

i try to use a template engine called Chunk Templates (similar to velocity) in my android project (get at https://code.google.com/p/chunk-templates/). While using it i need to get access to a template file in my assets folder:

```
Theme t = new Theme("path to file"); //path getAssets()..? file:///....?
Chunk c = t.makeChunk("template"); //template.chtml
c....
```

The "template.chtml" is located in my eclipse folder "assets\themes\template.chtml"
When running it on my device the templating engine says, template not found.

What path do i have to use?

Greetings,
Hamzty

Comment: `Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/roboto-light.ttf");` Used to get fonts, change it accordingly to use themes

Comment: good idea but goolge says its just for fonts...=( (also createFromAsset)

Comment: did any of the below solution worked ?

Comment: i tried all of them but neither worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i wrote an email to the author and the solution is still not published and will be added in a future distribution. i got an experimental version in which the code looks like the following:

```
AndroidThemeLoader loader = new AndroidThemeLoader(getBaseContext());
Theme theme = new Theme(loader);
Chunk chunk = theme.makeChunk("test#subtest");
chunk.set("name", "Dennis");
String html = chunk.toString();
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String baseURL = null;
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseURL, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Thank you everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("your file");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i need a path to instantiate my Theme class new Theme(String path)

Answer (score 0):

Try `InputStream instream = getAssets().open("file.xxx");` to access a file in assets folder from your Activity class.

EDIT:

You can also try it this way : http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample?example=string&loc=en_US#input-java-EG1

A little bit of manual hard coding will be required but I think it will work.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer- with this method i can put the file in a stream but my theme variable cannot handle Streams. it needs a string without which should be the path where the chtml file is located

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to get an absolute path, you can create a `File` though by using the input stream and an output stream pointing to a new file. Check the Chunk Template documentation or raise this issue with the authors.

Comment: yeah could be an alternative way doing it but not the best one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
file:///android_asset/themes/template.chtml
```

Comment: Hi, if i try this i got false...=(: File f = new File("file:///android_asset/themes/template.chtml");
  System.out.println(f.exists());